# why vendor.js file size is different for local build and Azure CI/CD pipeline?

Tags: angular, azure-devops, cicd

On local when I build my angular project the size of vendor.js is 4.42 MB
[image: On local when I build my angular project the size of vendor.js is 4.42 MB]

whereas, on Azure through CI/CD pipeline the file size is around 14 MB, any thoughts??
[image: whereas, on Azure through CI/CD pipeline the file size is around 14 MB, any thoughts??]

I have used below command

```
ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I manage to resolve the above thing, the command on the devops was not taking the **--prod** flag, so I have added the script in the 'package.json'

```
 "build-prod": "ng build --prod"
```

and schedule the build-prod command in the pipeline -
[image]

build size after making the changes-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the following things:

1. Save the '**`vendor.js`**' file from the CI/CD pipeline to your local machine to check its size.
2. Compare the '**`vendor.js`**' file generated from the CI/CD pipeline with the '**`vendor.js`**' file generated from the local build to see if there is any difference between the contents of them.
3. Add a self-hosted agent on your local machine to run the CI/CD pipeline, and then check the size of the generated '**`vendor.js`**' file.